# No data being added to the Database except an I.D

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, jsf-2

i am trying to add a value a user selects on the u.i. to a specific column in the database, i have got the connection to the database working, when i press save a new id is added to the database, no errors are shown in the console, but the value i want to submit is not put into the database at all, how can i achieve this ?

This is the code for the gui

```
                               <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner80-100" value="#{markingBean.spinnerNumber1}" 
                                           stepFactor = "1"  min="80" max="100" disabled = "#{formBean.number != 8}">  
                                    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />  
                                </p:spinner> 
                    <p:commandButton action="#{markingBean.markSectionOne}" value="#{bundle.buttonSave}" update=":growl" icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
```

This goes to a bean called markingBean

```
 private Marking markSectionOne;

    private MarkingService markingService;

    @Inject
    private MarkingFacade markingFacade;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.markSectionOne = new Marking();
    }

    public void markSectionOne() {
        this.markingFacade.create(this.markSectionOne);
        this.setMessage("Mark Saved");
    }
```

The create class in the abstractFacade

```
public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}
```

This would result in an id added to the database, but not the markSectionOne mark being added to the column called markSectionOne, why is this,

the entity class for marking is :

```
@Entity(name = "MARKING")
public class Marking implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String markingStage, markingCompleted, markSectionOne, markSectionTwo, markSectionThree, markSectionFour, markSectionFive, overalMark, plagorism, feedback, comments;
```

The only time i get an error is when i click save twice, i get the error in the console :

```
WARNING:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL140219165944320' defined on 'MARKING'.
Error Code: -1
Call: INSERT INTO MARKING (ID, COMMENTS, FEEDBACK, MARKSECTIONFIVE, MARKSECTIONFOUR, MARKSECTIONONE, MARKSECTIONTHREE, MARKSECTIONTWO, MARKINGCOMPLETED, MARKINGSTAGE, OVERALMARK, PLAGORISM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [12 parameters bound]
```

Could it be i am only trying to add one value when there are 12 columns ?

Comment: Is the managed bean action being invoked? Is the Entity manager persisting the data? Is there an error message to look at?

Comment: Nope error messages at all to look at, i get the mark saved ajax message, nothing in the console at all, and the i.d. have been added to the db thats all

Comment: Also it should be noted the i.ds are not one after each other they are random

Comment: Are you committing the transactions?

Comment: How can i check that out ?

Comment: Added an error i get if i submit the form twice, looking at the error, the value is not getting passes

Comment: Looks like you aren't filling the data in your object. Also, make sure to assign a new instance of `Marking` to your `markSectionOne` after saving it, this is, in your managed bean.

Comment: Hi there could you give me an example if possible as I'm un sure what you mean

Comment: Inside `public void markSectionOne`: `markSectionOne.setMarkingStage("foo"); this.markingFacade.create(this.markSectionOne); markSectionOne = new Marking();`...

Comment: Thanks a lot :) i have now got a string to be entered into the right column, one final question - how can i pass the value of the spinner to the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You're not filling the data in the fields of the object you will insert into database.
2. You're trying to insert the same object ou used in the previous transaction, which contains the auto generated id. Since this id is the primary key of your table, when trying to insert a new row with an already inserted id, it will give you an error message related to duplicated unique or primary keys. This is the relevant part of the error message: *duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint*.

To solve the problems:

1. **Change** the name of your method `markSectionOne`. No method of your class should have the same name of a field in it. You can change it to `saveMarkSectionOne` or something that helps the code readability.
2. **Create** getters and setters for your `markSectionOne` field in your class. These methods are recognized by being `getXxx` and `setXxx`, camel case. In this case, the methods would look like:

   ```
   public Marking getMarkSectionOne() {
       return this.markSectionOne;
   }
   public void setMarkSectionOne(Marking markSectionOne) {
       this.markSectionOne = markSectionOne;
   }
   ```

   With these changes done, now you can easily bind the data to your view using the power of JSF. Assuming there's an `int spinnerField` field in your `Marking` class with its respective getters and setters, you can bind it to the value of the spinner like this:

   ```
   <!--
       This acts as markingBean.getMarkSectionOne.getSpinnerField() when rendering
       and as markingBean.getMarkSectionOne.setSpinnerField(spinner.getValue()) when sending the request to the server
   -->
   <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner80-100" value="#{markingBean.markSectionOne.spinnerField}"
       stepFactor="1"  min="80" max="100" disabled="#{formBean.number != 8}">
       <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />
   </p:spinner>
   ```

   Do similar for other fields and components in the view.
3. Last but not least, you should also assign a new instance to `markSectionOne` field after inserting it in your database. You can achieve this by creating a new instance inside `saveMarkSectionOne` method:

   ```
   public void markSectionOne() {
       //supposing the data in markSectionOne is filled...
       this.markingFacade.create(markSectionOne);
       this.setMessage("Mark Saved");
       //after saving...
       markSectionOne = new Marking();
   }
   ```

Comment: @user2962401 check that part of the answer: ***Assuming** there's an `int spinnerField` field in your `Marking` class*...

Comment: Thanks i added a  private int spinnerField; with the getters and setters, but for some reason it is still showing up as unkown property

Comment: Sorry do you mean in the marking entity class, not the marking controller class ?

Comment: @user2962401 make sure that your `markingBean` class has a getter and setter for your `markSectionOne` field, to recompile the code and redeploy the application.

Comment: @user2962401 I meant the `Marking` class, not `MarkingBean`.

Comment: Ah thank you :D i have now managed to get it all working, thanks a lot for you detailed answer, it has really helped me understand what i was doing wrong and what was needed to make it right :) thanks again

Comment: would you mind having a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909285/how-to-submit-two-pieces-of-data-to-a-db-in-one-query

it is the same as this one but this time im trying to add more data to the db but am unable to