# How to submit two pieces of data to a db in one query

Tags: java, jpa

I am able to save a value from a combo box to the relevant column in my DB, but what I am trying to do now is add data to another column within the same table in the same query, but I am unsure of how to structure the query

The data I am trying to include as well is studentNumber, which is a variable that already has a static value assigned in the backing bean:

```
//For testing untill other memebers get some code working, on which i require
private int studentNumber = 500198;
```

the way in which I am currently add data to the DB is:

```
<p:spinner id="ajaxspinner80-100"
    value="#{markingBean.markSectionOne.markSectionOne}" stepFactor="1"
    min="80" max="100" disabled="#{formBean.number != 8}">
    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />
</p:spinner>
```

user selects a value from a spinner:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{markingBean.markSectionOne}" value="#{bundle.buttonSave}" update=":growl" icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
```

presses save and goes to this code in the markingController:

```
public String markSectionOne() {
    //supposing the data in markSectionOne is filled...
    this.markingFacade.create(markSectionOne);
    this.setMessage("Mark Saved");
    //after saving...
    markSectionOne = new Marking();
    // now navigating to the next page
    return "/lecturer/marking/marking-section-two"; 
}
```

which saves it to the DB.

I now want to add the student number in the same query to save the studentNumber to the column studentNumber in the DB

EDIT

this is my entity class for the marking table

```
@Entity(name = "MARKING")
public class Marking implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String studentNumber,markingStage, markingCompleted, markSectionOne, markSectionTwo, markSectionThree, markSectionFour, markSectionFive, overalMark, plagorism, feedback, comments;
```

Comment: What do you mean by *add the student number in the same query to save the studentNumber to the column studentNumber in the db*?

Comment: i am trying to add the value of student number (500198) from to the database which has the column student number

Comment: You should specify the structure of your table and the field in your class that maps to this column. Note that this problem is completely unrelated to JSF.

Comment: Thanks i added the entity class that creates the table, what i am trying to is submit the student number from the u.i. to the table column studentNumber in the same transaction as the spinner value

Comment: EDIT: after reading over @Luiggi answer to my question i have been able to do it, so once again thank you luiggi :D